# Slow insert performance when connecting to RDS from EC2 instance using Docker containers and Rust SeaORM, despite same VPC and sufficient resources

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, rust, amazon-rds

I am relatively new to AWS and I am facing a performance issue when inserting data into my RDS PostgreSQL instance from an EC2 instance running Docker containers using Rust's SeaORM library. Both the RDS and EC2 instances are in the same VPC, and I have verified that their resource usage is well within limits. What puzzles me is that when I SSH into the EC2 instance and use psycopg2 to forward the queries to the RDS, the insert operation is significantly faster.

Here's the scenario:

- I am running a set of Docker containers on an EC2 instance using the bridge network driver.
- I am using Rust's SeaORM library to insert around 70,000 rows of data, which is approximately 10 MB in size.
- When inserting the data directly from the Docker containers, it takes about 30 seconds.
- When connecting via SSH to the EC2 instance and then forwarding the queries to the RDS using psycopg2, it takes about 4 seconds.

I am not sure why there is such a significant difference in performance. Since both the RDS and EC2 instances are in the same VPC and their resources are not limited, I would expect the direct connection from the Docker containers to the RDS to be at least as fast as the SSH approach, if not faster.

Can anyone shed some light on what might be causing the slow performance when connecting to RDS from the Docker containers on the EC2 instance? Is there something I may have overlooked in terms of network configuration or other settings? Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What if you use psycopg2 from inside docker? Seems like the problem is either docker or rust so you should be able to rule one out this way.

Comment: Thanks for the quick comment. Ideally I want to avoid this since I'm using an orm but I forgot to add in the post I tried a direct connection from inside the docker container using psql and no luck, the orm has the same performance as psql which leads me to think it isn't a rust issue

Comment: What is your EC2 spec and have you checked bandwidth limits of your container networks?

Comment: It's unclear from your question if you're sending exactly the same queries over the wire (N+1 queries, separate queries vs. batching, transaction modes etc.) and reading the results back in the same manner. Instead of changing two things at once (seaorm+ec2 vs. psycopg2+ssh) you should try narrowing it down to one variable and then investigate that.